# mySQL select top user with top download hits

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have a table that stores user info  with each row structured like:

```
(int) FileId |(int) userId | (int) DownloadHits | (varchar) UserName
```

Each user may have a lots of files uploaded by their names.
I want to show a list of user that have top download hits, look like :

```
userId    UserName     DownloadHits
  1          Key             120  
  2          Bob             50  
  3          Zero            15
```

I tried SUM method but it only show the top one user. 
Is there any solution for this query ?

Comment: Are there different user name relevant to same userId ?

Comment: i think the data sample is a bit off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select userid,username,
sum(downloadhits) as theDowns
from tblName
group by userid,username
order by theDowns desc
```

Comment: Working with your idea ...

Work like a charm !

Comment: best to have a user table to join to get that username and not replicate it in the stats table. otherwise if Bob becomes Robert, problems